# PhpStorm default code inspection setting

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, code-inspection

PhpStorm is really good at inspecting code errors and warnings but sometimes we does not like warnings popped up we only interested in code errors. I tried to find global settings for code inspection in IDE but could not find any related option. I have to manually change setting on every opened file.

Does anyone have found the global option?

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: There is no such option to set highlighting level for all project. Consider better to adjust the [Inspection profile](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/customizing-profiles.html) for the Project rather than disable all the inspections highlighting.

Comment: That popup is per file ONLY. If you do not like certain inspections --- just disable them globally or on per scope level (you can create custom scope where you will include only desired or unwanted files) and change inspections for that scope only -- just like Andrey said.

Comment: can you kindly share where i can set that type of scope ? :)

Comment: Go to Settings/Preferences screen and type `scope` in search box. In any case: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/scopes.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-inspection-for-different-scopes.html